# Django model classes with the same field names and Admin

Tags: django, class, django-admin

I have a model which has been working up until now. The model has 2 classes that both have some fields with the same name. I had admin customised for class1 but not 2, although class 2 was registered with the admin so I could edit it. Now I want to customise class2 in the admin but then I start getting _ *name* _ errors.

I think it is caused by the field names being the same in the different classes.

How can I setup the admin so it will work with 2 nearly identical classes

Comment: Show us your classes, and the way you register them with the admin, otherwise I for one have no idea how to help.

Comment: ... and the tracebacks for the errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the error was being caused by:

```
filter_horizontal = ('screenshots')
```

Note the missing comma after the screenshots item:

```
filter_horizontal = ('screenshots',)
```

Thanks for having a look